# How can I add an interactive view controller inside of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my project I have a UITableView that holds horizontal scrolling UICollectionViews. So each cell in the table view is a new collection view. I need to have an interactive view on the left side of each cell. That view will be collapsed along the left side, but if you tap that view, it will animate open a little bit. If the collection view is scrolled all the way to the left, i.e. the beginning, it will be open. Once a user starts scrolling the collection view it will automatically close.

Here is a visual example:

Table View Cell..

```
The view is collapsed in this image.
____________________________
|V |                       |
|i |    CollectionView     |
|e |    Scrolls </>        |
|w_|_______________________|    


The view is open in this image. The ways it opens are described above.
____________________________
|V      |                  |
|i      |  CollectionView  |
|e      |  Scrolls </>     |
|w______|__________________|
```

How would I be able to have this interactive controller on the left side of my cell, which already has the collection view within?

Also if there are any 3rd party controls for something like this, that would be great also!

Answer (score 1):

That would be a `UIView` - not a `UIViewController` - that is placed to the left of the `UICollectionView`.

Inside the `UICollectionView` delegate method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you could expand and retract the `cellLeftSideView` whenever the first collection view cell is visible:

```
if ([[cell_CollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]) {

    // First item IS showing in collection view
    // Make sure left side view is expanded

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect aFrame = cell_LeftSideView.frame;
        aFrame.size.width = kCellLeftSideView_Width_Max;    // <= #define maximum width value
        cell_LeftSideView.frame = aFrame;
    }];
}
else
{
    // First item is NOT showing in collection view
    // Make sure left side view is shrunk

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect aFrame = cell_LeftSideView.frame;
        aFrame.size.width = kCellLeftSideView_Width_Min;    // <= #define minimum width value
        cell_LeftSideView.frame = aFrame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Inside of that expanding box I will need to have other items that will contain data, that is why I was thinking a view controller. It will have an image and a label. Also I am wanting to have it to where the use can tap that view at any point to expand or close it. Would I just add a UITapGesture to that view and perform the appropriate action upon tapping it?

Comment: Exactly. Subclass the `UITableViewCell` and add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside `awakeFromNib`